# cron setting in cPanel error

Tags: wordpress, cron

I use wordpress 4.9.6 and civiCRM 5.1.2 for wordpress
in my cPanel:
string command:

https://mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username&pass=password=curl '[string site-key]'

message mail:
You need to send a valid key to execute this file. 
Why my key it's not valid? I took the key in cvicrm.settings.php
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The cron url seem to be wrong, it should have been

```
https://mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=<username>&pass=<password>&key=<site-key>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with:
https://mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username&pass=password=string-site-key
**without curl** 
but I still have problems
I have a doubt: do I have to change the cron.php file?
username
password
site-key
Thanks

Comment: with:   https://mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=<username>&pass=<password>&key=<site-key>    message is: /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: admin: No such file or directory

Comment: *in case it can serve someone* 
with this code I no longer receive an error message in my e-mail; even the CiviCRM system status no longer reports errors; I didn't insert quotation marks, this is code: 

wget -O / dev / null -q -t 1 https: //site/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=my-admin&pass=my-pass&key=xxxxxx

Comment: Yeah you need to add them in quotes. Congrats you made it work.

Comment: OH!    still mistake!     wget -O /dev/null -q -t 1 https://my-site/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=my-admin&pass=my-pass&key=xxxxxxxxxx
-jailshell: *syntax error near unexpected token `)'*

Answer (score 0):

The administrator manual has a section on how to setup the cron command. https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cron